# Update Python setuptools on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, setuptools

Is it possible to update Python `setuptools` on Heroku?

I get this error when deploying to Heroku:

```
remote:        ERROR: google-auth 1.18.0 has requirement setuptools>=40.3.0, but you'll have setuptools 39.0.1 which is incompatible.
```

Answer (score 3):

The version of `setuptools` appears to be [hard-coded into the `heroku/python` buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/122722f89e46dcc1a71271c00e538b1e9ac796c6/bin/steps/python#L160), with the latest release (tagged as `v170`) using `setuptools-39.0.1`. The `master` branch shows the same thing, so I don't expect to see an official release upgrading `setuptools` anytime soon.

The easiest solution might be to use an older version of `google-auth` that doesn't require newer `setuptools`. [`v1.6.3`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/releases/tag/v1.6.3) [looks like it should work](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/08272d89667a901d0dff6c4ba53d5b30fcc29e81/setup.py#L21-L26).

You could try explicitly depending on `setuptools>=40.3.0` in your `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile`, though I'm not sure how well that will work.

Or you could fork the `heroku/python` buildpack, modify it, [and use it](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#using-a-third-party-buildpack), though the maintenance burden of doing so is likely to be high. There might even be an existing [third-party buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/search/buildpacks?q=python) that does what you want, though I didn't see one on a quick search.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the line `setuptools==40.3.0` to your `requirements.txt` file and it will work.

You could also try to update your python version in the `runtime.txt` file because I think heroku update setuptools directly with python module updates.